# append parameters to url in jquery and reuse them them in code behind asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, url

i have an aspx page (URl like **XYZ.aspx** ) and in that am showing some **10 images and data** and colors of images as filter on page_load event, and when click that color filter i am making an ajax call and getting corresponding data and replacing old data and showing these **2,3 image result**. and my URL doesn't change since it's ajax call, and if i refresh the page (**XYZ.aspx**) it will again show that 10 images and data. but i want to append that selected color to the url (like **XYZ.aspx/Color-blue,red**) when i do the ajax call, and if i refresh the page having the url **XYZ.aspx/Color-blue,red** then i can able to read those parameters in code behind and get those related **2,3 images** and show in the page_load event, instead of **10 images and data**. how should i do that any best way to do that, this is already implemented u can see in flipkart filters in product listing page.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you can manually save this URL using a special browser object called history. So, before you make the ajax call, append your color parameters to the url string, i.e. like this

```
var url = <url of your controller method> + "?color=blue,red;
```

Then save this url using method of the history object - `pushState`, something like this:

```
history.pushState({ url }, "", url);
```

This will change your url in a browser address bar, so when you refresh the page, necessary data will be loaded from the server.

Use this url in your ajax request (without setting parameters).

On the server side make the controller method accept a `string` parameter and fetch your data (I believe that's the way you've done it already).
Take into account that when you navigate backward/forward with browser buttons, you should manually perform some actions to restore this state.

When I thought about this a little more, I realised that you can run into one problem. When you refresh the page, you will receive only data without the corresponding view. To solve that you can check if it is an ajax call or not (calling `Request.IsAjaxRequest()`), and return data/view with data (one of those that matches your needs).

Comment: Hi thanks for ur help but one thing, what do u ment by Use this url in your ajax request (without setting parameters).  ??

Comment: I just meant that your parameters would be in your url, so there is no need to write them in data section of your ajax method